# Is there a way to prevent an object in a list from printing more than once?

Tags: python, random

So I’m creating a python code to randomly pick one question out of all the questions I have in my list. When I run the code, it randomly picks one question out of the list of about 200 questions and shows it to me. I want to answer this question and then move on to the next one. However, I don’t want to keep getting the same question after I’ve already answered it. Is there a any way to make sure that once a question has been printed, it is removed from the list so it can’t appear again? Because I could have gone through all but one question and have to go through multiple other questions I’ve already answered before I get to the particular one I haven’t answered. So is there a way I can make sure no question can be printed more than once?(I don’t want to print all questions using random.sample k=200 as I don’t want to know what question is coming next.) Any response will be deeply appreciated.

My code currently looks like this:
import random

questions= [
'define math',
'define french',
'define english',
]

results = random.sample(questions, k=1)
print(results)

Except with 200 questions

Comment: Do you have some piece of code to show what solutions you have tried so far?

Comment: I didn’t try out any solutions cause I couldn’t think of any. The code basically looks like this:                                                                                          import random

questions= [
 'define math',
 'define french',
 'define english',
]

results = random.sample(questions, k=1)
print(results).                                                                                                     Except with 200 questions

Comment: Well, put that piece of code into your question then. :)

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"I don't know how to do this" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: However, I'll shorten your search for you: look up `random.shuffle`.  Look up solutions using it.

Comment: Oh. I didn’t realise. Sorry this is my first post. Thank you!

Comment: And I have obviously tried to solve this problem. All my luring just made 0. Sense as i had no idea how to start. The code was once a random.choices code but i changed it to random.sample because I thought it old work. I just didn’t no where to start a tally getting on trac. Thank you for replying though!

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want `my_list.pop(index)` which will remove the item at `index` and return it (so if you don't want to completely throw out the question you could append the results to another list)

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you could clarify as i you were talking to a beginner for me that would be appreciated. If not, that’s ok too. I could use a YouTube video to learn more about it. This is how my ode looks now if yo want to se it for reference import random

questions= [
 'define math',
 'define french',
 'define english',
]

results = random.sample(questions, k=1)
print(results).                                                                                                       Except with 200 questions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can choose items randomly from list using [`random.randrange()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange). And after you're done with the item, you can remove it from the list.

Repeat until the list is empty.

```py
import random

questions = [
    'define math',
    'define french',
    'define english',
    'define spanish',
    'define czech',
    'define slovak',
    'define whatever',
]

while questions:
    # Select random index from the remaining list.
    index = random.randrange(0, len(questions))

    # Do whatever you want with the selected item.
    selected = questions[index]
    print(selected)

    # Remove the just-selected item from the list using its known index.
    questions.pop(index)
```

Output:

```
define whatever
define english
define slovak
define spanish
define czech
define french
define math
```

Comment: `selected = questions.pop(index)` gets the item and removes it in one operation.

Comment: That's correct _(thus the upvote)_, but that doesn't have to be what you always want, if you need to avoid data loss _(for example if you `pop` right away and there's an error raised on the next line, you might have to do extra work to make sure you don't lose the item you just removed from the original list)_.

Comment: Thanks but I want only one question to be printed. I want it so only one question gets printed and once it has been printed, it cannot show up again when I tap ‘run’. Is that possible? Thanks again for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Sure like this:

```
if not x in myList:
  myList.append(x)
```

Where x is the random number. Other trick is to later convert list to set and back to list:

```
myList = list(set(myList))
```

As per as your need:

```
import random 
questions= [ 'define math', 'define french', 'define english'] 
results = random.sample(questions, k=1) 
if results not in questions:
  questions.append(results)

print(questions)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I haven’t tried it yet but I will soon. If you could clarify a bit to beginner level that will be appreciated but if not, that’s okay too. I could watch a YouTube video to understand better. My code looks like this:     import random

questions= [
 'define math',
 'define french',
 'define english',
]

results = random.sample(questions, k=1)
print(results)                                                                                                                                                                   If you want to use it for reference. Thanks again!

Comment: Edited please check

Comment: Your solution seems to work except it prints more than one of the questions despite k being equal to 1. Thank you for answering once again.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way of simply creating permutations which guarantees that in the next N picks all the N questions are picked and is probably even much faster than the pure python approach:

```py
import numpy as np
N=len(sample)
random_order=np.random.permutation(N)
for i in random_order:
    next_question=question[i]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is *almost perfect*. This code randomises all the questions but prints them as one block. Is there a way, keeping the randomised form of the questions, to make it so the first question in the output appears and then the next does and then the next does. For reference, this is hw my code looks:

Comment: My code looks like this:                                                  import numpy as np
import random

questions= ['define math', 'define french', 'define english',]

N=len(questions)
random_order=np.random.permutation(questions)
for i in random_order:
    next_questions=questions[0]

print(random_order)